# How to style Menu border/outline in JavaFX8 using CSS?

Tags: css, java-8, javafx-8, styling

i'd like to customize the appearance of a Menu in my JavaFX8 application. How can i get rid or style the color of the 'white outline' shown in the following screenshot?

[image]

i tryed:

```
#MainMenuBar
{
    -fx-text-fill: #bbbbbb;
    -fx-background-color: #3c3f41;
    -fx-border-color: #555555;
    -fx-border-style: solid;
    -fx-border-width: 0 0 1px 0;

}

.menu-item
{
    -fx-background-color: #3c3f41;
        -fx-text-fill: #bbbbbb;
    -fx-border-color: transparent;

}
```

but it still there is this white otuline.

Thx,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

seems you have to also style the 'context-menu'.

it worked by adding:

```
.context-menu 
{
    -fx-background-color: #3c3f41;
    -fx-border-color: #555555;
    -fx-border-style: solid;
    -fx-border-width: 1px;
}
```

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12299162/how-to-style-menu-button-and-menu-items) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21912946/how-can-i-style-a-javafx-menu-and-its-items-in-css) answers on SO helped me to figure it out, thanks all.