# JavaFxSceneBuilder - Styling MenuItem

Tags: css, javafx, scenebuilder

I am trying to style my menu-item, but so far unsuccessful.

[Hierarchy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3zDHF.png)

I tried below css, but nothing. Can anyone help?

```css
.menu-bar .menu:openvertically .arrow-button .arrow{

 -fx-background-color:red;

}
```

I don't understand how to access the children of MenuBar.

I could, however change the Menu, using CSS below.

```css
.menu-bar .menu:openvertically .label{
 -fx-text-fill: orange;
 -fx-padding: 5 0 0 20;
 -fx-font-size: 18pt;

}
```

Thanks!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21912946/how-can-i-style-a-javafx-menu-and-its-items-in-css