# JavaFX CSS - Font color in MenuItem

Tags: css, javafx, colors, menuitem, menubar

I am styling my MenuBar in JavaFX and I have been trying to change the font-Color 
of the text in the MenuItem but no success.

this is my CSS code.

How could I do it?

```
.menu-bar {
    -fx-background-color: darkslategray;
    -fx-opacity: 0.5;
}

.menu-bar .menu-button:hover, .menu-bar .menu-button:focused, .menu-bar .menu-button:showing {
    -fx-background: -fx-accent;
    -fx-background-color: darkslategray;
    -fx-opacity: 0.5;
    -fx-text-fill: -fx-selection-bar-text;
}



.menu-item {
    -fx-background-color: darkslategray;
    -fx-padding: 0em 0em 0em 0em;
    -fx-text-fill: greenyellow;
}


.context-menu {
    -fx-skin: "com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.ContextMenuSkin";
    -fx-background-color:darkslategray ;
    -fx-background-insets: 0, 1, 2;
    -fx-background-radius: 0 6 6 6, 0 5 5 5, 0 4 4 4;
    -fx-padding: 0.333333em 0.083333em 0.666667em 0.083333em; /* 4 1 8 1 */
    -fx-opacity: 0.9;
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to style menu button and menu items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12299162/how-to-style-menu-button-and-menu-items)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To style the text of the **menu-item** in css, you have to select the **label** of the menu-item using `.menu-item .label{....}` like,

```
.menu-item .label{
    -fx-text-fill: greenyellow;
}
```

I hope this solved your problem.

Comment: An incredible useful resource, when it comes to figuring out which class needs to be changed is this overview: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html