# How do you dynamically change the background color of a JavaFX MenuItem at runtime?

Tags: javafx, colors, background, menuitem

There's no setBackground method in the class and setStyle("-fx-background-color: green;") doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

[Look up this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12299162/how-to-style-menu-button-and-menu-items),
Although setStyle and "-fx-background-color:green" should also work for text's background-color when working with MenuItems